# Degree of freedom in survival::pspline

Tags: r, survival, splines

What is the relationship between the `df` in `survival::pspline` and the number of knots?
Say I want to fit a curve made up of **cubic polynomials** and has ***N internal knots***. What would should I set for `df`? I don't really understand this from the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.22/topics/pspline).

Secondly, when I fit a model, say
`fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + pspline(age,3), lung)`,
and look at fit$coefficients, there terms ps(age)3 until ps(age)12. What does this mean?

I have read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517375/splines-relationship-of-knots-degree-and-degrees-of-freedom) but I am not sure I fully understand how it translates to my case.

Comment: Close-voters: I believe the first question is primarily about its *statistical* content, and this should therefore stay open. [See here.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352)

Comment: Although the second part is software-specific to R, it's more about how to *interpret the output of statistical software*, which should be on-topic too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be thinking about `pspline()` similarly to a cubic regression spline. That's not how it works. It's a simple form of a *smoothing* spline. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/559708/28500) compares different smoothing methods. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579990/28500) compares `pspline` smoothing and the regression splines implemented by the `rcs()` function in the `rms` package, in the context of a Cox model.

If you want to specify knot positions between which unpenalized cubic functions are fit, then you are talking about regression splines. The approach of `pspline()` is different. It sets up a series of basis functions spaced evenly across the limits of the predictor values and produces a *penalized* regression coefficient for each of the basis functions.

If you specify a value for `df` and don't specify boundary knot locations, then the default `nterm` argument is `round(2.5*df)` (8 in your example) and knots to join the basis functions are placed according to the following code:

```
dx <- (Boundary.knots[2] - Boundary.knots[1])/nterm
knots <- c(Boundary.knots[1] + dx * ((-degree):(nterm - 1)), 
        Boundary.knots[2] + dx * (0:degree))
```

where the default `Boundary.knots[2]` and `Boundary.knots[1]` are the limits of the data range and `degree` is 3 for a cubic fit.

The multiple coefficients that you see reported are for each of the corresponding basis functions between the knots. Each of those coefficient values, however, is *penalized* or reduced in magnitude from what it would be in a fully fit model. The result is a less wiggly curve than an unpenalized fit would produce.

The `df` argument to `pspline()` effectively determines how wiggly the final fit is. That's useful if you have decided to [spend a certain number of degrees of freedom](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar.html) on modeling a continuous predictor and prefer the smoothing spline to the regression spline approach. The penalization then results in a number of degrees of freedom that is substantially less than the number of knots. Alternatively, if you specify `df = 0` the modeling will find optimal smoothing based on the Akaike Information Criterion.

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/518434/28500) goes into more detail about what a Cox model fit with a `pspline()` term reports.

Comment: Thanks @EdM -- love your answers!  
I don't understand exactly what pspline's "df" means then? If df=3 gives 8 coefficients, it's not really interpretable as degrees of freedom? If we use rms::rcs(x,1), it says the number of knots must be >=3. Does this mean this number includes the boundary knots? Also if the location is not specified, Is this fitted by AIC?

Comment: @Snoot the `df` value is the _effective_ degrees of freedom devoted to that predictor in the model. With penalized coefficients it's the _effective_ df that matters for statistical analysis and estimates of overfitting, not the total number of associated coefficients. Without penalization, those are the same. The more the penalization, the lower the effective df. Frank Harrell give a brief summary [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/586038/28500), with a link to more information.

Comment: @Snoot parameterization differs among implementations of splines. The `rcs()` function uses unpenalized regression splines, not the penalized splines of `pspline()`. For `rcs()` you specify the total number of knots including "boundary" knots, but its default is to place the "boundary" knots somewhere within the range of data values instead of at the extremes. That's unlike the `ns()` function in R, which by default places them at the extremes. With a regression spline, the fit is forced to be linear outside the boundary knots.

Comment: Thanks a million @EdM, you are a wealth of knowledge!